# How to recover data from /var/www?

Tags: data-recovery, www

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

I created directory inside `/var/www/demo`, and placed some files there. By mistake I pressed the delete button, and my files were deleted. Now I don’t have these files. So how to recover my data from this `/var/www/` directory.

Comment: Before you start recovering you might want to search for the files - sometimes you just misplace the files somehow. Try this in the Terminal: "sudo find / -name *.html". Switch out for .php if that is what you are using. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If these files were deleted with the Nautilus file manager they will be in the Trash bin. By default the Trash bin is the icon in the bottom right of the screen.

If the files were deleted with the command line then the files cannot be recovered easily. There are some tools to "undeleted" files but I never used any of those.

Comment: i delete my file using the delete button from the key board. but i never found from the Trash.

Comment: And were you inside a Nautilus file manager or in some other application when you pressed delete?

Comment: was `/var/www` on your local drive or running on a remote server/system?  if it's on a remote system it will be extremely hard to recover the files

Comment: If he deleted it with Nautilus then he was probably running it as root, maybe `/root/.Trash` or something?

Comment: it was /var/www on your local drive, then ?

Answer (score 1):

if this were not found, to recover deleted files you can use `testdisk`

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

I've used it, and all files recovered.

Answer (score 0):

The files were deleted as a root user. You would find them in `/root/.local/share/Trash/files` (For versions older than Ubuntu 11.10, you would find them in `/root/.Trash`).